# Turn MultiIndex Series into pivot table design by unique value counts

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

```
Sample Data:

Date,code
06/01/2021,405
06/01/2021,405
06/01/2021,400
06/02/2021,200
06/02/2021,300
06/03/2021,500
06/02/2021,500
06/03/2021,300
06/05/2021,500
06/04/2021,500
06/03/2021,400
06/02/2021,400
06/04/2021,400
06/03/2021,400
06/01/2021,400
06/04/2021,200
06/05/2021,200
06/02/2021,200
06/06/2021,300
06/04/2021,300
06/06/2021,300
06/05/2021,400
06/03/2021,400
06/04/2021,400
06/04/2021,500
06/01/2021,200
06/02/2021,300


import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(testfile.csv)

code_total = df.groupby(by="Date",)['code'].value_counts()
print(code_total)

Date        code
06/01/2021  400     2
            405     2
            200     1
06/02/2021  200     2
            300     2
            400     1
            500     1
06/03/2021  400     3
            300     1
            500     1
06/04/2021  400     2
            500     2
            200     1
            300     1
06/05/2021  200     1
            400     1
            500     1
06/06/2021  300     2

dates = set([x[0] for x in code_total.index])
codes = set([x[1] for x in code_total.index])
    
test = pd.DataFrame(code_total,columns=sorted(codes),index=sorted(dates))

print(test)
```

Is there a way to transpose the second index into a column and retain the value for the counts? Ultimately I'm trying to plot the count of unique error codes on a line graph. I've been searching up many different ways but am always missing something. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try reset_index() after the groupby.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(by="Date",)['code'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Thanks man! I cant believe i missed this.